# How to assign hot key to reduce/increase screen brightness in old sony VAIO laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts, sony-vaio

I use a VPCEH2KFX Sony VAIO laptop. After I installed windows 10 and the keyboard shortcut drivers from sony website, non of the hotkeys that was defined for Fn + F1 to F7 except volume keys still does not work.
Does anyone know the reason and the solution to reassign these hotkeys?

Answer (score 0):

Sony haven't released anything for that machine since 2014. It's abandonware, I'm afraid, never supported for Windows 10 & no longer supported for Windows 7 either.

See DriverScape - https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/sony/laptops-desktops/vpceh2kfx/44381
Sony's own page for it just seems broken, no matter what browser you try to access it from - https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/product/vpceh2kfx/downloads I've tried from 2 OSes & three browsers, all give the same 'Chrome doesn't work' notice… even though I never used Chrome at all.

Comment: Not sure if a utility such as AutoHotkey, https://www.autohotkey.com/ , or Clavier+ could work. There are scripts to change screen brightness, for example, https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/125563-universal-screen-brightness-changer/ .